# How i can generate QR Code using my iPhone/iPad Application?

Tags: ios, ios4, qr-code

I have some information like Name,company Name,Company Url,etc using this information i want to generate QR code for that so is there any free api is available for that or is there any way to generate QR code for this purpose?

Comment: How do you want it to be implemented ? Will it generate the new QR Code every time or just for once,to let other scan that QR Code?

Comment: yes i want such kind of Mechanism if I provide all these above detail it should return me QR Code for that.

Comment: Try looking for a [qr code generator](https://www.qrcode-tiger.com/) with a free API. They already have the robust backend built so why not ask for access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. I have placed one of the example in this answer.

For This answer we are using QR code of 200 x 200 size. for more details [see here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/overview.html).

QR code Google API below

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=MECARD:

Example:

URL encoded:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=MECARD:ORG%3AArchitect+Of+The+Capitol%2CN%3ABarack+Obama%2CTEL%3A%28202%29+224-3121%2CADR%3A1331+F+St+NW+%23+SB15+Washington%2C+DC+20004-1107%2CEMAIL%3Awww.firstgov.gov

Normal URL:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=MECARD:ORG:Walmart Stores Inc,N:Mike Duke,TEL:(479) 273-4000,ADR:702 SW 8TH ST BENTONVILLE, AR 72712-6209,EMAIL:www.walmartstores.com

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this project wraping c code for iPhone:

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

```
Just couple of steps & you are done :
1) Attach the libz.dylib library to your target in Xcode.
2) Drag the QRDraw and libpng folder files into your project.
3) Update the Header Search path under build settings menu.
```

Hope this is enough for integration within your app.

Comment: Hi, I can successfully added this into my project and it works perfectly for the first time. if i try to regenerate without closing the app. then the app crashes and gets closed automatically. Can you help me?

Comment: @dinesh you can post some code , wherever you have make the changes within the example.Otherwise it;s quite difficulty to guess the solution for this, since there would be something related to memory nothing else or please make sure that your scanner class object should not get released for the second time.

Comment: Thanks and you are right. please have a look at this link. I have placed my code. Please help me.

Comment: if you want use ZBar and QRDraw too ?

Comment: @iTux I am not sure about QRDraw but yes that works for ZBar.